# how to avoid duplicate data with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How do I avoid duplicate data when we enter the same data again? instead, I want to issue a warning:

> sorry your username has been used

I'm using php script, I have done it to overcome duplicate data but the results have unexpected errors.

This is my code, please correct it if you wish. thanks

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $npm_siswa = $_POST['npm_siswa'];
    $nama_siswa = $_POST['nama_siswa'];
    $bidangst_siswa = $_POST['bidangst_siswa'];
    $ipk_siswa = $_POST['ipk_siswa']; 

    $query ="INSERT INTO class(npm_siswa, nama_siswa, bidangst_siswa, ipk_siswa) VALUES('$npm_siswa','$nama_siswa','$bidangst_siswa','$ipk_siswa')";

    $insert_data = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $goto = header('location: input_data.php');
    if (headers_sent($goto) == true) {
        exit();
    }
}

$checking = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE npm_siswa ='$npm_siswa'";

$process = mysqli_query($con, $checking) or die(mysqli_error());
while($row_filter = mysqli_fetch_assoc($process)) {
    $kelasId = $row_filter['kelasId'];
    $npm_siswa = $row_filter['npm_siswa'];
    $nama_siswa = $row_filter['nama_siswa'];
    $bidangst_siswa = $row_filter['bidangst_siswa'];
    $ipk_siswa = $row_filter['ipk_siswa'];
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($process) > 0) {
    echo "maaf nama anda sudah digunakan"; 
} else {
    $data = "INSERT INTO class(npm_siswa, nama_siswa, bidangst_siswa, ipk_siswa) VALUES('$npm_siswa','$nama_siswa','$bidangst_siswa','$ipk_siswa')";
    $check = mysqli_query($con, $data);
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Having code-comment not in English make it much harder to understand...

Comment: have included the code, sorry if my code uses the Indonesian language in writing because I come from Indonesia

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to first select rows from mysql using a select statement, and then check if the array is empty.

```
$checking = "SELECT * FROM class WHERE npm_siswa ='$npm_siswa'";

$process = mysqli_query($con, $checking) or die(mysqli_error());

if(empty($process)) {
    echo "maaf nama anda sudah digunakan"; 
} else {
    $data = "INSERT INTO class(npm_siswa, nama_siswa, bidangst_siswa, ipk_siswa) VALUES('$npm_siswa','$nama_siswa','$bidangst_siswa','$ipk_siswa')";
    $check = mysqli_query($con, $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: make sure that it is the DBMS that controls the uniqueness, with a `UNIQUE` constraint. Then test your `mysqli_query`'s return value to handle the error.

```
$process = mysqli_query($con, $checking);
if (!$process)
{
   // Handle your error
}
```

**Pros** : Only one query

**Cons** : The error is not necessarily due to the UNIQUE constraint